# Dash-Plolty does not show images on the figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to put images on my figure, like a watermark, I am following the [documentation.](https://plotly.com/python/images/) and it works with the 'Vox' example. However, when I try to put local images to the figure they do not show up.

**Here is my code**:

```
import plotly.express as px
import requests
import pandas as pd 


response = requests.get("https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/1/address/0x343A53A1E8b17beDd15F47a28195Bc8C120d4443/portfolio_v2/?format=format%3Dcsv&key=ckey_57eeb470248541708eeaf028c9d").json()['items']
data=pd.json_normalize(response,record_path=['holdings'],meta=['contract_ticker_symbol','contract_name',"contract_address"])
data['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%D')



#colors = {
  #  'background': 'black', #Sets plot background color black
   # 'text': '#FFFFFF' #Sets plot text color white
#}
fig = px.line(data, x="timestamp", y="close.quote", color="contract_name",color_discrete_sequence=["#ff4c8b", "#00d8d5",'#f7f7f7'], line_group="contract_ticker_symbol",labels={    #Changes colum names
                    "contract_name":'Contract Name', 
                     "timestamp": "Date",
                     "close.quote": "USD Value",
                     "contract_ticker_symbol": "Ticker"
                 }, title='Asset Value Over Time', hover_name="contract_ticker_symbol")

fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source="vox.png",
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0.5, y=0.24,
        sizex=0.5, sizey=0.6,
        xanchor="center", yanchor="bottom"
    )
)


fig.add_layout_image(
            dict(
                source="aa_footer.svg",
                xref="paper", yref="paper",
                x=0.7, y=(-0.20),
                sizex=1.7, sizey=.8,
                xanchor="center", yanchor="bottom"
            )
        )
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='black', paper_bgcolor='black',font_color='#FFFFFF')

# update layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(r=20, l=300, b=75, t=125),
    title=("Asset Valuation Overtime<br>" +
           "<i>Assets in Ethereum Blockchain</i>"),
)
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False) #hide vertical gridlines

fig.show()
```

I tried with both putting my images into 'assets' folder and outside as well as uploading them to imgBB. still no response

This is the figure I am getting:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: do you run it on local computer? Server can't get local files.

Comment: did you try to download `vox.png` and use it as local file? Did you get the same problem? Maybe problem is only your local images.

Comment: it works when I use it with dash but not with plotly

Comment: if it doesn't show error message in system terminal/console or in JavaScript console then there is no clue what can make problem. Do you run it on local computer or server? Did you try `/full/path/to/image` -maybe it runs in different folder then you expect and it can't find it with relative path.

Comment: don't you get error? It shows me syntax error because there is useless `)` before `fig.update_xaxes`

Comment: I am running it on local computer. Also I tried to download vox.png it does not show up as well

Comment: Try it now, I was editing my post maybe I accidentally deleted something

Comment: I can't run it but first I would try `"/full/path/to/vox.png"` and I woulc check `current working directory` - `print( os.getcwd() )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to specify the data obtained by using the PILLOW library as the source. The official reference description can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/images/#add-a-background-image).

```
from PIL import Image # new import

img = Image.open('./data/vox.png') # image path
# defined to source
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source=img,
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0.5, y=0.24,
        sizex=0.5, sizey=0.6,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="bottom",
        opacity=0.5
    )
)
```

[image]